# How do we currently handle Wubi questions for 13.04 and later?

Tags: discussion, scope

> The Discussion

Wubi's been dropped from 13.04.  They no longer test it, and they no longer support wubi in 13.04.  [There was a developers mailing list post about proposing to drop Wubi](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html), and [they removed the Wubi builds for everything but 12.04](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/037000.html).

Therefore, if I am interpreting this correctly, there are no Wubi builds for anything but 12.04.  Should we consider any Wubi questions for anything that is 13.04 or newer as offtopic now, since it's no longer being supported?

---

> ***The Solutions***

For new questions that are similar to "Can I use Wubi on 13.04", [Oli's answer here is most suitable.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6509/10616)

For new questions about debugging Wubi builds that are from older beta builds that have Wubi on them for 13.04, [Luis Alvarado's answer is the most suitable.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6505/10616)

Any questions about 13.10 and Wubi, however, are offtopic and should either be closed as not supported, or Oli's solution should be utilized.

Comment: What in the... :O

Comment: The download page advertises a 12.10 build and [the instructions given](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) are for 12.10.

Comment: @Oli you missed a revision on my question, then, because I noticed that three seconds after the dev team told me... :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wubi discussion (AGAIN) - Supported Here on Ask Ubuntu? (13.04 and later)](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Despite its flaws, Wubi has certainly been an extremely popular method for letting Windows users install Ubuntu. I wouldn't be surprised if demand for it remains high enough for something to either officially or unofficially replace it in the future.

**And why off-topic?** Ubuntu 13.04 is what we are supporting here. Somebody asks a question about it, we should answer. In this case there could be one question: "How do I install 13.04 with Wubi?" with the single answer: "You can't -  wubi support dropped in 13.04" and dupe anything else against that.

Bruno has offered one up which I'd suggest we dupe against: [Will I be able to use wubi to install Ubuntu releases newer than 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280667/will-i-be-able-to-use-wubi-to-install-ubuntu-releases-newer-than-12-10)

That would be a much healthier way of dealing with this because it would get people to a full answer.

---

**An update from the future**: [Wubi support was never dropped](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7596/449). It's still on-topic for 12.04 onwards. It's still a valid method of installation.

However it [probably] doesn't work with UEFI and by extension almost certainly doesn't work with SecureBoot and by extension, we can pretty much guarantee it *currently* won't work with modern Win8 laptops.

In those cases feel free to answer: "No, Wubi won't work on your laptop." or dupe against something else that explains that.

Comment: As such? http://askubuntu.com/questions/280667/will-i-be-able-to-use-wubi-to-install-ubuntu-versions-higher-than-12-10

Answer (score 8):

I think we should support Wubi on versions that support Wubi. For example, **users asking for Wubi on 13.04+ would be off-topic**. Users asking for Wubi on a still supported version of Ubuntu like 12.04 would still get help until the version finishes their EOL support.

The support time frame should also count since, in May, Ubuntu 11.10 for example will end support, so any 11.10 question after that (Wubi or not) will be closed and the user recommended to seriously upgrade the system.

Comment: I iwasn't saying drop overall wubi support, I was saying specifically for 13.04 and up.  (new data: 12.10 is still shipping with wubi, but NoNewBuilds with wubi)

Comment: I agree. 12.04 and 12.10 will be around for a while yet. Some people are still using 10.04, 11.04 and 11.10.. :O

Comment: Agreed with Seth.  The dev team confirmed 12.10 still has Wubi, but 13.04 and onwards won't.  Starting now, I propose we mark all 13.04 Wubi questions as offtopic.

Comment: People upgrade Wubi installs. To talk about how to install 13.04 with Wubi is one thing, but to be running 13.04 on a Wubi install is another.